# Loading many files at once?

Tags: r

So let's say I have a directory with a bunch of .rdata files

```
file_names=as.list(dir(pattern="stock_*"))

[[1]]
[1] "stock_1.rdata"

[[2]]
[1] "stock_2.rdata"
```

Now, how do I load these files with a single call?

I can always do:

```
for(i in 1:length(file_names)) load(file_names[[i]])
```

but why can't I do something like `do.call(load, file_names)`?
I suppose none of the apply functions would work because most of them would return lists but nothing should be returned, just that these files need to be loaded. I cannot get the `get` function to work in this context either. Ideas?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

`lapply` works, but you have to specify that you want the objects loaded to the `.GlobalEnv` otherwise they're loaded into the temporary evaluation environment created (and destroyed) by `lapply`.

```
lapply(file_names,load,.GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Hi sir, since my `RData` are big ones, I wanted to use `library(parallel)
mclapply(c(RData1, RData2, RData3),load,.GlobalEnv, mc.cores = parallel::detectCores())` by imitating your approach in a multi-core way, however, this only returns lists of  loaded RData environment names (characters) despite long time loading, what could possibly go wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

For what it's worth, the above didn't exactly work for me, so I'll post how I adapted that answer:

I have files in `folder_with_files/` that are prefixed by `prefix_pattern_`, are all of type `.RData`, and are named what I want them to be named in my R environment: ex: if I had saved `var_x = 5`, I would save it as `prefix_pattern_var_x.Data` in `folder_with_files`.

I get the list of the file names, then generate their full path to `load` them, then `gsub` out the parts that I don't want: taking it (for `object1` as an example) from `folder_with_files/prefix_pattern_object1.RData` to `object1` as the `objname` to which I will `assign` the object stored in the `RData` file.

```
file_names=as.list(dir(path = 'folder_with_files/', pattern="prefix_pattern_*"))
file_names = lapply(file_names, function(x) paste0('folder_with_files/', x))
out = lapply(file_names,function(x){
  env = new.env()
  nm = load(x, envir = env)[1]
  objname = gsub(pattern = 'folder_with_files/', replacement = '', x = x, fixed = T)
  objname = gsub(pattern = 'prefix_pattern_|.RData', replacement = '', x = objname)
  # print(str(env[[nm]]))
  assign(objname, env[[nm]], envir = .GlobalEnv)
  0 # succeeded
} )
```

Comment: The accepted answer also didn't work for me, as I only got a list with the object names of the loaded files. But here's what did it: loaded <- lapply(info, function(x){get(load(x,.GlobalEnv))})

Comment: The accepted answer worked for me. Depending on your file paths, you might need to specify full.names = TRUE in the dir() function for Joshua's answer to work.

Comment: @Wave Your approach worked for me too. Consider adding it as an anwser.

Answer (score 4):

**Loading many files in a function?**

Here's a modified version of [Joshua Ulrich's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3764352/1083960) that will work both interactively and if placed within a function, by replacing `GlobalEnv` with `environment()`:

```
lapply(file_names, load, environment())
```

or

```
foo <- function(file_names) {
  lapply(file_names, load, environment())
  ls()
}
```

Working example below. It will write files to your current working directory.

```
invisible(sapply(letters[1:5], function(l) {
  assign(paste0("ex_", l), data.frame(x = rnorm(10)))
  do.call(save, list(paste0("ex_", l), file = paste0("ex_", l, ".rda")))
}))

file_names <- paste0("ex_", letters[1:5], ".rda")
foo(file_names)
```

Answer (score 0):

To upload multiple R objects as elements in a list within the `GlobalEnv`, you need to use the following.

```
filenames <- list.files(file.path(getwd()), pattern='\\.RData$', full.names=T)
results <- sapply(filenames, function(x) mget(load(x)), simplify = TRUE)
```

Edited code from *bannister* user in [Github](https://gist.github.com/bannister/8002800)