# With R, loop over data frames, and assign appropriate names to objects created in the loop

Tags: r

This is something which data analysts do all the time (especially when working with survey data which features missing responses.) It's common to first multiply impute a set of compete data matrices, fit models to each of these matrices, and then combine the results. At the moment I'm doing things by hand and looking for a more elegant solution.

Imagine there's 5 `*.csv` files in the working directory, named `dat1.csv`, `dat2.csv`, ... `dat5.csv`.  I want to estimate the same linear model using each data set.

Given [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758084/loop-in-r-loading-files), a first step is to gather a list of the files, which I do with the following

```
csvdat <- list.files(pattern="dat.*csv")
```

Now I want to do something like

```
for(x in csvdat) {
    lm.which(csvdat == "x") <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = x)
}
```

The "which" statement is my silly way of trying to number each model in turn, using the location in the csvdat list the loop is currently up to. that is, I'd like this loop to return a set of 5 lm objects with the names `lm.1`, `lm.2`, etc

Is there some simple way to create these objects, and name them so that I can easily indicate which data set they correspond to?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another approach is to use the `plyr` package to do the looping. Using the example constructed by @chl, here is how you would do it

```
require(plyr)

# read csv files into list of data frames
data_frames = llply(csvdat, read.csv)

# run regression models on each data frame
regressions = llply(data_frames, lm, formula = y ~ .)
names(regressions) = csvdat
```

Comment: More elegant solution than mine. My +1 to come, but see @Henrik response which is what the OP was looking for.

Comment: @ chi Both your solution and Ramnath's will serve the questioner better in the long run.

Answer (score 10):

Use a list to store the results of your regression models as well, e.g.

```
foo <- function(n) return(transform(X <- as.data.frame(replicate(2, rnorm(n))), 
                                                       y = V1+V2+rnorm(n)))
write.csv(foo(10), file="dat1.csv")
write.csv(foo(10), file="dat2.csv")
csvdat <- list.files(pattern="dat.*csv")
lm.res <- list()
for (i in seq(along=csvdat))
  lm.res[[i]] <- lm(y ~ ., data=read.csv(csvdat[i]))
names(lm.res) <- csvdat
```

Comment: +1 that is definitely a good and Rish way. But, the OP wanted single variables, so `assign` is the way to go...

Comment: @Henrik Agree. (btw, you could replace your `paste` command with `sep="."`, but I won't be able to upvote more :-)

Comment: @chl good point with `sep="."`. Furthermore, loading the data in the call to `lm` is also pretty neat I think (then one could put everything in one line!).

Comment: @chl thanks for the insight on loading data within the lm call.

Comment: Definitely the way to go. Just because a client asks you for an inefficient implementation that will require more work for him doesn't mean you shouldn't offer a better one.

Comment: just had the idea of enhancing this with preallocating : `lm.res <- vector("list", length(csvdat))` would potentially save some time on bigger operations.

Answer (score 8):

what you want is a combination of the functions `seq_along()` and `assign()`

`seq_along` helps creates a vector from 1 to 5 if there are five objects in `csvdat` (to get the appropriate numbers and not only the variable names). Then `assign` (using `paste` to create the appropriate astrings from the numbers) lets you create the variable.

Note that you will also need to load the data file first (was missing in your example):

```
for (x in seq_along(csvdat)) {
    data.in <- read.csv(csvdat[x])   #be sure to change this to read.table if necessary
    assign(paste("lm.", x, sep = ""), lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = data.in))
}
```

`seq_along` is not totally necessary, there could be other ways to solve the numeration problem.

The critical function is `assign`. With assign you can create variables with a name based on a string. See `?assign` for further info.

---

Following chl's comments (see his post) everything in one line:

```
for (x in seq_along(csvdat)) assign(paste("lm", x, sep = "."), lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = read.csv(csvdat[x]))
```

Comment: Good that you point to `assign`. (I'm out of votes today, but be sure I'll upvote ASAP.)