# Call a data.frame found in a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, apply

I've imported multiple files read.table and named each as file1, file2, file3,...
I've put all of the data.frames (read.table files) into a list:

```
ClassFilter <- function(x) inherits(get(x), 'data.frame' )
Objs <- Filter( ClassFilter, ls() )
```

Now I want to call each data.frame (e.g. file1) and do a column mean:

```
for(x in 1:NumberOfFiles){
  mean[NumberOfFiles:400] <- apply(Objs[[x]],2,mean)
}
```

The problem is Objs[[x]] is giving me an error "Error in apply(Objs[[x]], 2, mean) : dim(X) must have a positive length" as the element in the list is not pointing to the data.frame. Anyone know how I can make the list element point to the data.frame from which the list was created initially? Thank you

Comment: (1) I would investigate [reading the files directly](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5758084/324364) into a list, which bypasses the need for `get`. (2) Be careful using `apply` on data frames. If you have columns that aren't numbers, you won't like the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Objs` contains the names of the `data.frame` variables, so you must get the variable first using `get()` function:

```
for(x in 1:NumberOfFiles){
  Mean[NumberOfFiles:400] <- apply(get(Objs[x]),2,mean)
}
```

or if you prefer you can also "evaluate" the variable name:

```
for(x in 1:NumberOfFiles){
  Mean[NumberOfFiles:400] <- apply(eval(as.name(Objs[x])),2,mean)
}
```

Also, as correctly pointed out by @SeñorO you should give a different name to `mean` object to avoid conflicts with the function mean.

Comment: I'd also suggest naming the object `Mean` so it doesn't conflict with the function `mean`

Comment: Thank you, I feel kind of stupid I was trying to do this for an hour now.