# Passing arguments for variables in a function

Tags: r, function, syntax

I am brand-new to R and trying to understand the basic syntax of functions.

In both of the functions `f(x1)` and `g(x,1)` below, I would like to generate `y=2`. Only the former works.

I'm familiar with the `str_interp()` and `paste()` functions, but those seem to work only in the context of strings, not variables. E.g., `prefixnum <- str_interp("${prefix}${num}")` doesn't solve the issue.

My motivation is that I'd like to call a function by specifying components of variable names. My background is in Stata, where placeholders are designated with a backtick and a tick (e.g., `prefix'`num'). I've consulted a few [relevant](https://www.matthieugomez.com/statar/macros.html) [resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691390/r-equivalent-of-stata-local-or-global-macros), to no avail.

As an aside, I've read varying thoughts about whether variables should be prefixed with its dataframe (e.g., `df$var`). What is the logic behind whether or not to follow this convention? Why does `f(df$x1)` work, but writing `f(x1)` and modifying the function to be `y <- df$var*2` not work?

```
df <- data.frame(x1=1)

f <- function(var) {
  y <- var*2
  y
}
f(df$x1)

g <- function(prefix,num) {
  y <- df$prefixnum*2 #where "prefixnum" is a placeholder of some sort
  y
}
g(x,1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly you are trying to pass column name as an argument to the function. You can try to paste `prefix` and `num` together to get column name and use that to subset dataframe.

```
g <- function(data, prefix, num) {
  y <- data[[paste0(prefix, num)]] *2 
  y
}

g(df,'x', 1)
#[1] 2
```