# Creating an Array of Dataframes in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to create an array of dataframes in r. I have many many csv files, and I want to put them all into separate data frames using a loop.

```
data1[1] <- "C:/data1.csv"
data1[2] <- "C:/data2.csv"

for(i in 1:2) {
 data2[i] <- data1[i][,-1]
 rownames(data2[i]) <- data1[i][,1] }
```

Any suggestions on how to make this work?

Comment: This is quite confusing, and your sample code is not really a MWE (minimum working example). What is `data1`? And I don't think you want to assign the string `"C:/data1.csv"` to the variable `data1` but rather the data in that file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `list.files` to list my files by pattern.
lapply to loop through the list of files and create a list data.frame with read.csv.

```
temp <- list.files(pattern="data.*[.]csv",full.names=TRUE)
named.list <- lapply(temp, read.csv)
```

Comment: `pattern` is a regex, not a `glob`.

Comment: Sidenote: an actual glob example that I found interesting [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5759013/324364).