# How to read many files using a loop in R

Tags: r

I am trying to open many .csv files in a folder, and read one value in each csv file. The csv files have the same structure, but different names, such as factory.01.csv, factory.02.csv, etc. Is it possible to read them in R using a loop? If so, how to write the loop? Thanks.

Comment: Here's a handy answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758084/loop-in-r-loading-files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    setwd("WHATEVER-YOUR-WD-PATH-IS")

#Create a list of all file names in directory
#Save File names to a variable

    filenames <- list.files(pattern="factory+.*csv")

## Get names without ".CSV" and store in "names"

    names <- substr(filenames, 1, 10)

## Read in all data frames using a loop

    for(i in names){
      filepath <- file.path(paste(i,".csv",sep=""))
      assign(i, read.csv(filepath, sep = ",", header=FALSE, skip=1))
    }
```