# I have folder which has 200 of .xlsx files..I need to convert them in to txt files

Tags: r

I want to convert 100 excel document lying in "C:/Users/hp/Desktop/excel" to .txt format..I am triyng to use lapply so that all of them are converted to txt at one go..
Please help me ..
if I have one file I am converting the .xlsx document to txt in the following way
library(xlsx)

```
sink("output.txt")

data=read.xlsx("C:/Users/hp/Desktop/excel/test2.xlsx",1)

data

sink()
```

I am writing following code to do it recursively

```
dest <- "C:/Users/hp/Desktop/excel"

dir(dest)

myfiles <- list.files(path = dest, pattern = "xlsx",  full.names = TRUE)

lapply(myfiles,function(x)  system(sink(x) data=read.xlsx(myfiles,1) data 
sink()),fullnames=TRUE)
```

After having done for .xlsx it has to be done for .docx also

Comment: Your code in the `lapply` is wrong syntactically, cannot work (probably a copy/paste problem). Is there a reason you aren't using `read.xlsx(...)` followed by `write.csv(...)` or one of the text file variants?

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you identify exactly how you expect your text files to be formatted. For example, comma-delimited, tab-delimited, or aesthetically-oriented R-console-output (not good for later programmatic consumption).

Comment: r2evans..This is what came to my mind
. I am beginner programmer
Actually I was trying to make a lapply function for this problem.

Comment: yes we can do it as follows .
dta=read.xlsx("C:/Users/Desktop/excel_p/abc.xlsx",1)
 write.table(dta,"abc.txt")


.But I am not getting it how to recursively do it for the folder using laaply

Comment: Perhaps this is useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5759013/3358272

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to export an Excel file to txt with the following code :

```
library(RDCOMClient)

xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xlApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE
xlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open("D:\\Excel_File.xlsx")
xlWbk$SaveAs(FileName = "D:\\Excel_File.txt", FileFormat = 42) # save to txt, see https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformatf
```