# loop keeping variable names R

Tags: r, loops

I would like to create a loop over 3 data frames and creates subsets of each and assign to these new subsets a new name. How can I loop over these three data frames while maintaining the names?

For example, I have 3 data frames: apples, berries, and grapes. When making a loop, is there a way to assign the new subset data frames similar names to their respective original data frame?

Written out without a loop, this is what the code would look like.

```
apples <- data.frame(type = c("red", "golden", "green"), number = c(1, 2, 3))
berries <- data.frame(type = c("blueberry", "raspberry", "mulberry"), number = c(1, 2, 3))
grapes <- data.frame(type = c("red", "green", "sour"), number = c(1, 2, 3))

apples_large <- subset(apples, number > 2)
apples_small <- subset(apples, number < 2)

berries_large <- subset(berries, number > 2)
berries_small <- subset(berries, number < 2)

grapes_large <- subset(grapes, number > 2)
grapes_small <- subset(grapes, number < 2)
```

Comment: It is better not to create multiple objects in the global env

Comment: How did you create these data.frames in the first place? It seems like if the values are related and you want to perform similar actions on them, they should all be in the same list. Then it's much easier to work with. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames and this related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51560385/2372064

Comment: Perhaps helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames#24376207

Comment: Look at the assign function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place the dataset objects in a `list` and `split` by the 'number' column to get a nested `list` of datasets

```
lapply(list(apples, berries, grapes), function(x) split(x, x$number>2))
```

If we create a named `list`, then it becomes easier to identify or extract the individual components

```
out <- lapply(mget(c("apples", "berries", "grapes")),
  function(x) split(x, c("small", "large")[(x$number > 2) + 1]))
out$apples$small
```

As @JonMinton mentioned if we need to drop the rows that have 'number' 2

```
lapply(mget(c("apples", "berries", "grapes")),
       function(x) {x1 <- subset(x, number != 2)
             split(x1, c("small", "large")[(x1$number > 2) + 1])})
```

Comment: Split only works if the splits are mutually exclusive and exhaustive. In the example the subsets were < 2 and > 2, so ==2 dropped.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bad idea to create many objects in the global environment, rather than keeping them in a list, but this would do it:

```
tmp <- c("apples", "berries", "grapes")

for (i in 1:length(tmp)){
  assign(paste0("big_", tmp[i]), subset(get(tmp[i]), number > 2))
  assign(paste0("small_", tmp[i]), subset(get(tmp[i]), number < 2))
}
```

(or use `seq_along(tmp)` instead of `1:length(tmp)`)

Notice the use of `assign` for the outputs and `get` for the inputs.

Comment: it's good to know how to do these things even though it's a bad idea to do them.

Answer (score 1):

First, put your `data.frames` into a `list`, then define a function that classifies the rows. Now you can `split` each element of the list according to your classifier in an `lapply`.

```
fruits <- list(
    apples=data.frame(type = c("red", "golden", "green"), number = c(1, 2, 3)),
    berries=data.frame(type = c("blueberry", "raspberry", "mulberry"), number = c(1, 2, 3)),
    grapes=data.frame(type = c("red", "green", "sour"), number = c(1, 2, 3))
)

clsfy <- function(num) {
    if (num>2) {
        ret <- "Large"
    } else if (num<2) {
        ret <- "Small"
    } else {
        ret <- NA ## if no condition is met, discard this row
    }
    return(ret)
}

fruits2 <- lapply(fruits, function(fr) {
    split(fr, sapply(fr$number, clsfy))
})
```

At this point, fruits2 looks like this:

```
>     fruits2
$apples
$apples$Large
   type number
3 green      3

$apples$Small
  type number
1  red      1


$berries
$berries$Large
      type number
3 mulberry      3

$berries$Small
       type number
1 blueberry      1


$grapes
$grapes$Large
  type number
3 sour      3

$grapes$Small
  type number
1  red      1
```

To generalize classifications using more than one column per row, you can use `apply` instead of `sapply` and re-define your `clsfy` function so that it takes the whole row: `split(fr, apply(fr, 1, clsfy))`. On the other hand, if your condition is really a simple binary, then `ifelse` is better than `sapply(x$number, clsfy)`.