# How to read multiple files with one read option

Tags: r

Having an option like this:

```
D <- readFiles("file (1).bib","file (2).bib","file (3).bib")
```

How is it possible to have a simple read for all. Something like this:

```
D <- readFiles("file (",1:3").bib")
```

Comment: Have you read [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758084/loop-in-r-to-read-many-files)?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thank you for your suggestion. I tried this `test <- lapply(Sys.glob("file.*bib"), readFiles)` but it is not working

Answer (score 1):

`readFiles` from the `bibliometrix` package is actually just a wrapper for `readLines`. But the way it is written does not play nicely with `lapply`, which makes it difficult to pass character objects with file names.

I would therefore simply stick with `readLines`:

```
library("bibliometrix")
files <- list.files(path = "path/to/your/bibfiles",
                    pattern = ".bib$",
                    recursive = TRUE,
                    full.names = TRUE)
D <- unlist(lapply(files, readLines, encoding = "UTF-8"))
```