# reading images in r program

Tags: r, image

I want to read 12 images at a time in R.
I don't know how to do it. I am complete new to working on images in R.
How can I read couple of images from a folder in my system?
I am using windows10 operating system. RAM 8 gb. CORE i5 processor.
GPU is Intel(R) HD Graphics 620.

I am able to read only single image in R and that image is displaying as numeric values. I tried to convert it into raster format and then tried to print image to view the image. But I am still finding the color codes in values but not the image in print.

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks a lot.

```
install.packages("magick")
library(magick)
install.packages("rsvg")
install.packages("jpeg")
library(jpeg)


img <- readJPEG("C:/Users/folder/Abc.jpg", native = FALSE)
img1 <- as.raster(img, interpolate = F)
print(img1)
```

I want to read couple of images at a time into R console and want to view or print images.

Comment: Duplicate to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758084/loop-in-r-to-read-many-files)?

Comment: Store images into a list.

Comment: Try eg: `lapply(list.files(pattern = ".png"),magick::image_read)`.Might need a `list/vector` to store your results.

Answer (score 0):

The suggested duplicate gives you the basics for how to read in a number of files at once, but there are a few potential gotchas, and it won't help you with displaying the images.

This first bit is purely to set up the example

```
library(jpeg)
library(grid)

# Create a new directory and move to it
tdir <- "jpgtest"
dir.create(tdir)
setwd(tdir)

# Copy the package:jpeg test image twice, once as .jpg and once as .jpeg
# to the present working directory 
file.copy(system.file("img", "Rlogo.jpg", package="jpeg"), 
  to=c(file.path(getwd(), "test.jpg"), file.path(getwd(), "test.jpeg")))
```

Then we can list the files, either using a regex match, or choose them interactively, then read and store the images in a list.

```
# Matches any file ending in .jpg or .jpeg
(flist <- list.files(pattern="*\\.jp[e]?g$"))

# Interactive selection
flist <- file.choose()

jpglist <- lapply(flist, readJPEG)
```

To display the images I tend to use `grid`, but there are a number of alternatives.

```
grid.raster(jpglist[[1]], interpolate=FALSE)
```

Remove temporary directory

```
setwd("..")
unlink(tdir)
```

[image]

Comment: I am getting "Error in rasterGrob(image, x = x, y = y, width = width, height = height,  : 
  object 'jpglist' not found"

Comment: I want to read multiple jpeg/jpg files  and save into a variable. How?

Comment: @krishna: Sorry, seems like i forgot a line while copying code over. should work now.

Comment: library(jpeg)
    library(grid)
    ##To create a folder
    tdir <- "jpgtest"
    dir.create(tdir)
    ##to set working directory
    setwd(tdir)
    ##to have a list of JPEG/JPG files
    (flist <- list.files(pattern="*\\.jp[e]?g$"))
    grid.raster(jpglist, interpolate = FALSE). The code is not working.

Comment: @krishna: Which part?

Comment: grid.raster(jpglist, interpolate = FALSE)

Comment: Is that still because object `jpglist` can't be found?

Comment: Error: unexpected symbol in "grid.raster(jpglist, interpolate = FALSE)."

Comment: Are you sure `jpglist` contains image data? Also you should use `jpglist[[1]]`, `jpglist[[2]]` etc. to access the individual images. If you want to display several at once you need to do something more advanced.