# Dynamically assigning CSVs to objects in a for loop in R

Tags: r, csv, analysis

I am trying to analyse monthly statements from last year which are in the form of CSV files. My attempted code is below. I want to import them all in one go, assign each to an object, and then filter each to get rid of some irrelevant data. Currently it throws me an error because the objects in the 'Months' list can't be found. I tried changing them to strings, but get a different error.

My ideal output is the CSV for each month listed as a dataframe object named after the month.

This is my first post so if this is poorly formatted or lacking detail, let me know what else to provide and I will edit this post. Please help this noob.

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)

Months <- c(Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, 
       Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec)

fileN <- c("2023-01-01", "2023-02-01", "2023-03-01", 
      "2023-04-01", "2023-05-01", "2023-06-01", 
      "2023-07-01", "2023-08-01", "2023-09-01", 
      "2023-10-01", "2023-11-01", "2023-12-01")

dir = "/R/" #I have anonymised this directory for privacy reasons

for(i in 1:12){
  FileP <- paste0(dir,fileN[i],".csv")
  Months[i] <- read_csv(FileP, show_col_types = F)
  Months[i] <- Months[i] %>% filter(
    Months[i]$`Transaction Type` != "Internal Transfer" &
    Months[i]$Amount < 0)
  }
```

When running it, this error is given:

> Error in UseMethod("filter") :
> no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "list"
> In addition: Warning message:
> In Months[i] <- read_csv(FileP, show_col_types = F) :
> number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Comment: If it says the file is not found, I don't know what else we can do. If you cannot guarantee that a file exists, then use `file.exists` to check before trying to read it. FYI, your sample code is not usable, your months are not quoted; you _could_ use `month.abb`, built in to R and containing what I believe you intend.

Comment: Having said that ... your `dir = "/R/"` means that you are looking for a file `"/R/2023-01-01.csv"`, which is at the root of your filesystem. You don't say that, but if you are on windows, that means `C:\R\2023-01-01.csv`; if on mac/linux, that's on the root filesystem, both seem unlikely.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/3358227, https://stackoverflow.com/q/5758084/3358272 for some recommendations for loading in multiple files.

Comment: You're piping in `Months[i]` to `filter()`, so when you filter, just pass the variable name `filter('Transaction Type' != "Internal Transfer" & Amount < 0). ` The error does not seem to be about file not found, but rather about `filter` receiving a list.

Comment: Hi @r2evans. I tried the months in quotes, but then they were turning out as lists rather than data.frames and I was getting an error:

Error in UseMethod("filter") :                                                                                                             
  no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "list"
In addition: Warning message:
In Months[i] <- read_csv(FileP, show_col_types = F) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Comment: @r2evans I am linking to files in linux in a folder called R, and this works fine assuming I have set my working directory appropriately. I changed the directory so my PC's username wasn't displayed for privacy reasons, and commented above that it was a changed directory but would work. Apologies if that has made the code less usable. I will check those attached links.

Comment: @guasi Yes, that seems to be the issue. How can I pass the variable name through but not as a list of strings? Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

You have to call each of the Month's elements as such:

```
for(i in 1:12){
  FileP <- paste0(dir,fileN[i],".csv")
  Months[i] <- read_csv(FileP, show_col_types = F)
  Months[i] <- Months[[i]] %>% filter(
    Months[[i]]$`Transaction Type` != "Internal Transfer" &
    Months[[i]]$Amount < 0)
  }
```

Note that I am extracting each element of the list using `Months[[i]]` and not `Months[i]`, as the latter returns a list of length 1, whereas the former returns the data frame corresponding to the ith element of the list.