# R read files with for loop

Tags: r, loops, statistics, stat

I just want to use use 10 files in R. For each I want to calculate something.
Exp. file:
stat1_pwg1.out
stat23_pwg2.out
..
stat45_pwg10.out

I try this:

```
for (i in 1:10){
Data=paste("../XYZ/*_pwg",i,".out",sep="")
line=read.table(Data,head=T)
}
```

But it does not work? Any hinds?

Comment: Quite similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/5758084/602276 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/3764292/602276

Answer (score 4):

I suspect your problem comes from the wildcard `*`.  A better way to do this might be to first store the file names using `dir`, then find the ones you want.

```
files <- dir("../XYZ",pattern="stat[0-9]+_pwg[0-9]+\.out")
for(f in files) {
  line=read.table(Data,head=T)
}
```

You could also use one of the `apply` family of functions to eliminate the for loop entirely.

Comment: You're welcome.  Since you're new to SO I will offer the following suggestion: If this answered the question please click the little checkbox to mark it as answered.  This will keep the question from being listed in the "unanswered" questions and helps keep the SO database tidy.

Comment: @gsk3: remember to escape the `.` in your regex.

Answer (score 2):

A few things about your code.

`paste` is vectorised, so you can take it out of the loop.

```
paste("../XYZ/*_pwg", 1:10, ".out", sep = "")
```

(Though as you'll see in a moment, you don't actually need to use `paste` at all.)

`read.table` won't accept wildcards; it needs an exact match on the file name.

Rather than trying to construct a vector of the filenames, you might be better using `dir` to find the files that exist in your directory, filtered by a suitable naming scheme.

To filter the files, you use a regular expression in the pattern argument.  You can convert from wildcards to regular expression using `glob2rx`.

```
file_names <- dir("../XYZ", pattern = glob2rx("stat*_pwg*.out"))
data_list <- lapply(filenames, read.table, header = TRUE)
```

For a slightly more specific fit, where the wildcard only matches numbers than anything, you need to use regular expressions directly.

```
file_names <- dir("../XYZ", pattern = "^stat[[:digit:]]+_pwg[[:digit:]]+\\.out$")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    files <- dir(pattern="*Rip1_*")

    files

    for (F in files){ assign(F , Readfunc(F))}
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.