# Manipulate same variable in a list of dataframes using lapply or Map

Tags: r, apply, lapply

I managed to import 10 `.csv` files by making use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759173/r-read-files-with-for-loop) elegant `lapply` solution.
The output now is a `list` of 10 `data.frames`.
Each data.frame contains the variables `year` and `value`:

```
 file_names <- dir("../XYZ", pattern = glob2rx("*.csv"))
 data_list <- lapply(filenames, read.table, header = TRUE)
 head(data_list[[1]])
  year     value
1 200712   2320,00 
2 200712   120,00    
3 200712   188,00 
4 200712   1328,00    
5 200712   46,00    
6 200712   98,00 
 head(data_list[[2]])
  year     value
1 200812   320,00 
2 200812   1120,00    
3 200812   1288,00 
4 200812   1128,00    
5 200812   746,00    
6 200812   938,00
```

Unfortunately, the variable `year` is formatted `yyyymm`, but I want it to be `yyyy`.

Hence I would like to use another `lapply` or `Map` to change the format of `year` in every single data.frame. Something like:

```
data_list <- lapply(data_list[["year"]], FUN = substr(1,4), ... )
```

or:

```
data_list <- Map(substr(1,4), data_list, "year")
```

But that doesn't work...Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
data_list <- lapply(data_list, function(x) {x$year <- substr(x$year, 1,4)
                                   x})
```