# Open file generated by loading .rda files

Tags: r

I followed your advice about creating a loop that loads files in R and did:

```
dataFiles<-lapply(Sys.glob("kwo*.rda*"), load)
```

Now I have my dataFiles which contains the files I wanted to load

```
head(dataFiles)

[[1]]
[1] "kw"

[[2]]
[1] "kw"

[[3]]
[1] "kw"
```

Now I need to work with the information contained in the files I loaded, what should I do to open the files and to 'identify' them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard behavior of load in this kind of loop is to create a temporary environment, load the data into it, and discarding this temporary enviroment again. If you want them in the global environment, you need to explicitly load them into the global environment, see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764292/loading-many-files-at-once) for more info. This will load all the objects contained in all the `.Rda` files into your global environment, aka workspace.

Could you provide some more information as to what you are doing exactly? What generated the Rda files, and what do you want to do with that data you read in? More information can help us, help you. And you refer to an earlier SO question your (I followed your advice about creating a loop that loads files in R), I cannot find this question in your profile.

Comment: +1? And if this solves your question entirely, mark it as the correct answer?

Comment: I generated the Rda files with the twitteR library. I need the data for doing regressions. The SO question I referred is 5758084 (Loop in R loading files). It was not directed to me though, but I mentioned as a reference.

Comment: I recommend you add a link to that question in your question above.

Comment: I tried to explicitly load the file into the global environment but couldn't load all the objects contained in all the .Rda files into my global environment. If I use the file 'dataFiles', generated through dataFiles<-lapply(Sys.glob("kwoil*.rda*"), load), I get this error message: In readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) : cannot open compressed file 'kwo', probable reason 'No such file or directory'

Comment: Thks. I have now an object containing the loaded files into the global environment. How should I access the loaded files (i.e. they are all called the same way as shown in the example)?@paulhiemstra

Comment: The objects had names when they where saved, e.g. `save(a,b,file="spam.rda")`. When loading the set of rda files into your workspace they are available under those names, i.e. `a` and `b` in my example.

Comment: Thks. The issue is that the objects were generated within a loop and have all the same name. How should I access them? I.e.     [,1]
 [1,] "kw"
 [2,] "kw"
 [3,] "kw"
 [4,] "kw"
 [5,] "kw"

Comment: If the objects are named identically, the objects are overwritten. I suggest changing the names in the loop where you save the objects.

Comment: To solve the issue of loading the objects named identically I'd need to build a matrix containing these files (which are lists). Could you give me some advice on making a loop? This matrix will be made of thousands of files (foo1, foo2,....) which are all the same length. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please create a new question.