# Load data frames into list

Tags: r, load, lapply

I am trying to load a bunch *.Rdata into a list.

```
files <- paste0("name", 1:10, ".Rdata")
data <- lapply(files, load)
```

This creates a list, where in each element has the name of data frame, but nothing else.

If I redefine files such that it only contains the first file, and call:

```
load(files)
```

Then is "works", but the file in 'files' is asigned to the global enviroment, which is not what I would like.

I would like to end up with a list, which in each element contains the dataframe. Such that then when I do data processing I can lapply over the list.

Comment: May be this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764292/loading-many-files-at-once `lapply(files, load, .GlobalEnv)`

Comment: Yeah I though about that. But that would create a bunch of files the global enviroment, would it not?

Comment: Sorry, when I commented, I read only the first part

Comment: Do you have multiple objects (data.frames) for each .Rdata

Comment: Try `lapply(files, function(x) mget(load(x)))`

Comment: There is only DF in each *.Rdata, and each DF is named acording to the * in *.Rdata

Comment: Can you try the code I posted? Not tested though.

Comment: Why not just load them all into an environment and then coerce with `as.list()`?

Comment: Yeah that did it, would you (Akrun) convert to an answer? And possible explain why this works, but not my "buggy" code?

Comment: Btw, if you have any control over how these files are created, you might try using the RDS format instead, via `saveRDS()` and `readRDS()`. That way, there is no need for `get()`, because there is a single object per file.

Comment: The RDS format is very neat, al though I do not have control over the input. I try to only save in that format, because of the object gets "unnamed".

Comment: @user3551644  Any problems with the `get/mget` solution?

Comment: Not really, for some reason each element in the list have two objects. Something called .Tranceback which is NULL. And then the data frame loaded. I got around this, by copying only list[[x]][2] to a new list.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try

```
lapply(files, function(x) mget(load(x)))
```

`mget` will return the value of the object(or objects) in a list.  In your `.Rdata` files, there is only a single 'data.frame' object per file.  So, even `get` should work.

In your code,

```
load(files[1])
```

The objects will be found in the global environment.  Suppose, the object is 'd1', by typing 'd1' on the console, you get the value of the object.  The same way

```
lapply(files, load, .GlobalEnv)
```

loads the object in the global environment, and can be accessed by typing. Your question, which I guess is to get the values in a list and that can be done with `get` or `mget`.

Answer (score 7):

Now tested, does work!

```
e1 = new.env()
invisible(lapply(files, load, envir = e1))
my_list = as.list(e1)
```

Comment: @user3551644 Whoops, of course it doesn't work because `lapply` doesn't return the environment so it just can't be nested. Fixed now.

Comment: This solution is very handy as it keeps the name of the object inside the list.