# Load all R data files from specific folder

Tags: r

I've got a lot of Rdata files which I want to combine in one dataframe.

My files, as an example, are:

```
file1.RData  
file2.RData  
file3.RData
```

All the datafiles have the structure: datafile$a and datafile$b. From all of the files above I would like to load take the variable `$a`and add this to and already existing dataframe called `md`. My problem isn't loading the files into the global environment, but processing the data in the RData file.

My code so far, which obviously doesn't work.

```
library(dplyr)
files <- list.files("correct directory", pattern="*.RData")
```

This returns the correct list of files.

I also know I need to `lapply` over a function.

```
 lapply(files, myFun)
```

My problem is in the function. What I've got at the moment:

```
myFun <- function(files) {
  load(files)
  df <- data.frame(datafile$a)
  md <- bind_rows(md, df)
}
```

The code above doesn't work, any idea how I get this to work?

Comment: Can you take out the `bind_rows` line out of the function and then `bind_rows(lapply(files, myFun))`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loading many files at once?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764292/loading-many-files-at-once)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
 library(dplyr)
 bind_rows(lapply(files, myFun))
#    a
#1   1
#2   2
#3   3
#4   4
#5   5
#6   1
#7   2
#8   3
#9   4
#10  5
#11  6
#12  7
#13  8
#14  9
#15 10
#16 11
#17 12
#18 13
#19 14
#20 15
```

where

```
 myFun <- function(files) {
    load(files)
    df <- data.frame(a= datafile$a)
 }
```

#### data

```
datafile <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=6:10)
save(datafile, file='file1.RData')

datafile <- data.frame(a=1:15, b=16:30)
save(datafile, file='file2.RData')
files <- list.files(pattern='file\\d+.RData')
files
```