# R: loading multiple RData with mclapply doesn't work

Tags: r, load, rdata, mclapply

I wanted to load multiple RData in one command, as explained by [Johua](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3764352/10580090) using

```
> lapply(c(a_data, b_data, c_data, d_data), load, .GlobalEnv)
[[1]]
[1] "nRTC_Data"

[[2]]
[1] "RTA_Data"

[[3]]
[1] "RTC_Data"

[[4]]
[1] "RTA_Data"

> rm(a_data, b_data, c_data, d_data); ls()
 [1] "nRTC_Data"       "RTA_Data"           "RTAC_data"     "RTC_Data"
```

However, since my RData are big, and I found no time improvement between `lappy()` and multiple `load()`, I decided to use multi-core approach like following:

```
library(parallel)
mclapply(c(a_data, b_data, c_data, d_data),load,.GlobalEnv, mc.cores = parallel::detectCores())
```

Though this significantly improved the loading time, also returns the list

```
   [[1]]
    [1] "nRTC_Data"
    
    [[2]]
    [1] "RTA_Data"
    
    [[3]]
    [1] "RTC_Data"
    
    [[4]]
    [1] "RTA_Data"
```

In my workspace, nothing is found

```
> rm(a_data, b_data, c_data, d_data); ls()
character(0)
```

I also tried replacing `.GlobalEnv` by `environment()`, but still didn't work.

Any one has a clue?

FYI, you can try with following commands:

```
> a = "aa";save(a, file = "aa.RData")
> b = "bb";save(b, file = "bb.RData")
> c = "cc";save(c, file = "cc.RData")
> d = "dd";save(d, file = "dd.RData")

> # lapply approach
> rm(list = ls())
> a = "aa.RData"; b = "bb.RData"; c = "cc.RData"; d = "dd.RData"
> lapply(c(a, b, c, d), load, .GlobalEnv); rm(a, b, c, d) 

> # mclapply approach
> rm(list = ls())
> a = "aa.RData"; b = "bb.RData"; c = "cc.RData"; d = "dd.RData"
> mclapply(c(a, b, c, d), load, .GlobalEnv, mc.cores = parallel::detectCores()); rm(a, b, c, d)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's because when using `mclapply` the underlying forking creates separate processes. In the code below I use `mclapply` with `myload` function that loads the Rdata file and returns the object loaded. The difference with your `lapply` version is that you have the data in the list returned by `mclapply`

```
myload <- function(x){
  x <- load(x)
  get(x)
}

a = "aa.RData"; b = "bb.RData"; c = "cc.RData"; d = "dd.RData"

res <- mclapply(c(a, b, c, d), myload, mc.cores = parallel::detectCores());
```