# Loading multiple RDS files save in the same directory using R

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I'm trying to load multiple .rds files that are save in the same directory. I have made a function for that and I iterate on a list of the files dir to load it but it doesn't work, see below that I write:

```r
markerDir="..."

markerFilesList <- list.files(markerDir,pattern = ".rds", recursive = TRUE, include.dirs = TRUE)

readRDSfct <- function(markerFilesList,markerDir,i){
  print(paste0("Reading the marker file called :",basename(markerFilesList[[i]])))
  nameVariableTmp=basename(markerFilesList[[i]])
  nameVariable=gsub(pattern = "\\.rds", '',nameVariableTmp)
  print(paste0("file saved in varibale called:", nameVariable))
  currentRDSfile = readRDS(paste0(markerDir,markerFilesList[[i]])) #nameVariable
  return(currentRDSfile)
}

for (i in 1:length(markerFilesList)){
 readRDSfct(markerFilesList, markerDir, i)
}
```

Does anyone has a suggestion for me to do it ?

thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764292/loading-many-files-at-once

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loading many files at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764292/loading-many-files-at-once)

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it correctly, you want to just load all the RDS, which are saved in the same directory in the R environment?

To load and bind all .RDS in one directory i am using something like this:

```
List_RDS = list.files(pattern="*.RDS")
List_using = lapply(List_RDS, readRDS)
Data_bind <-do.call("rbind", List_using)
```