# Why purrr:map () function is not working with load () to import Rda datasets

Tags: load, purrr, edgar

I have downloaded some `Rdata` files using `getMasterIndex` function from `edgar` package.

Now I am trying to load all of these files into RStudio using the following code -

```
paths <- list.files('Master Indexes', pattern = '[.]Rda$', full.names = TRUE)
files <- map (paths, load)
list_rbind(files)
```

The output of the `files` dataset is, but there should be data in it.

```
[[1]]
[1] "year.master"

[[2]]
[1] "year.master"

[[3]]
[1] "year.master"
```

The output of the code `list_rbind(files)` is -

```
Error in `list_rbind()`:
! Each element of `x` must be either a data frame or `NULL`.
ℹ Elements 1, 2, and 3 are not.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

However, the last `Rda` file is loaded in `RStudio` with the name being `year.master`

I have also used the `for loop` function, but the results remain the same.

I tried to take help from this page, but it does not work - [Using purrr to load multiple rda files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73192079/using-purrr-to-load-multiple-rda-files)

My goal is to put all of the Rda files into a list and then convert it into a dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Solution

Use this:

```
map(paths, ~ {load(.x); year.master}) 
# or map_dfr, if you want a dataframe as an output instead of a list
```

##### Explanation

Okay so first of all: clear your environment (or save your environment, and start a fresh one). If you're anything like me, then you have a lot of things in there that it makes it hard to see what is loaded.

Then run this code:

```
pacman::p_load(edgar, tidyverse)

useragent <- "Your Name Contact@domain.com"
getMasterIndex(2006, useragent) 
getMasterIndex(2022, useragent)

paths <- dir("Master Indexes/", full.names = TRUE) |> grep(pattern = "\\.Rda", value = TRUE)

example <- load(paths[1])

files <- map(paths, ~ load(.x, .GlobalEnv))
```

Afterwards, you'll see a few things in your environment:
[image: image of environment with year.master dataframe in it]

So you can see, even though (it seems) you were trying to load the files as
the object `files`, they aren't actually saved there, they're saved under another name, "year.master", and the function returns that name. It appears that the R objects are loaded with their (presumably original) name.

From the documentation:

> `load(<file>)` replaces all existing objects with the same names in the current environment (typically your workspace, .GlobalEnv) and hence potentially overwrites important data. It is considerably safer to use `envir =` to load into a different environment, or to `attach(file)` which load()s into a new entry in the search path.

In other words, because they all have the same name, running `map(paths, ~ load(.x, .GlobalEnv))` will load all of them, but you'll only get the last one, because every one after the first will overwrite the one that came before it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Then how can I load all of my files in the environment? I am just wondering whether there is any way.

Comment: yes, like I said at the top, use `map(paths, ~ {load(.x); year.master})`